# Javafx Button With EventHandler. Getting cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, button, javafx, eventhandler

I am trying to get a button to print out *Java is fun* after being clicked and I keep getting a *Cannot find symbol* error when I run it. I'm not sure whether it is my import statements or an actual error in the code itself. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why I'm getting the error?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;


public class ButtonHandler extends Application {
    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Pane pane = new Pane();

    Button btOK = new Button("OK");
    pane.getChildren().add(btOK);

    btOK.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
      System.out.println("Java is Fun");
    });

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(Pane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Button Demo"); // Set title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the error please

Comment: Java is case sensitive: `Scene scene = new Scene(pane);`

Comment: error: cannot find symbol , line 25

Comment: ok i did not see that thank you!

Comment: it is working now i cannot believe i did not see that thanks!